# How to add 1 day to the checkout date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to add 1 more day to the checkout, that is, end date must be greater than start date.

Here are my codes for the bootstrap datepicker:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate: new Date()
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate: new Date($('#from_date').val())
  });

  $('#from_date').on("blur", function() {
    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      minDate: new Date($('#from_date').val())
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="checkin">Check-in</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_date" name="checkin" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon">
     </span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="checkout">Check-out</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_date" name="checkout" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon">
    </span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What magic number have you tried to add to `minDate:new Date($('#from_date' ).val())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution among many would be to get `fromDate` in milliseconds via [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and add 1 day equivalent `milliseconds` to it:

```
var fromDate = $('#from_date').val();
// To date = fromDate + 1 day 
// milliseconds = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000
var toDateMillisecs = new Date(fromDate).getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000);
var toDate = new Date(toDateMillisecs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use moment [add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method for this in combination with [linked pickers](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers), after all you need to include the moment library to use the picker.

We set the [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) of the first picker to today using `moment()` and the [`maxDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) too for the date we choose one the other picker

The [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) of the check-out will be the day selected on the first +1

We listen to the changes using the events provided by the picker in this case [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange)

This way you don't have to be looking for the value of the textbox with blur all the time and it's pretty much easier to understand.

```js
$(function() {
  let $checkIn = $('#datetimepicker1');
  let $checkOut = $('#datetimepicker2');

  $checkIn.datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate: moment()
  });

  $checkOut.datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  });

  $checkIn.on("dp.change", function(e) {
    //Here we add a day more to the Check-out
    $checkOut.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date.add(1, 'day'));
  });

  $checkOut.on("dp.change", function(e) {
    $checkIn.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="checkin">Check-in</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_date" name="checkin" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon">
     </span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="checkout">Check-out</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_date" name="checkout" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon">
    </span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```